# ClassNotFound & No Suitable Driver, where did I go wrong?

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, connection

I have created a program that works perfectly in the IDE on NetBeans, but anytime I build the .jar file, the database connection stops working. I've already added the CLASSPATH to the MySQL Connector, as well as defined Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); Still nothing..

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gearheads";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","HellOnEarth202021");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        String pid = txt_staffID.getText();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name,timeraccess FROM staff WHERE staffid = '"+pid+"'");
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            String timeraccess = rs.getString("timeraccess");
            String staffName = rs.getString("name");
            getLogin = staffName;
            System.out.println(staffName);
            System.out.println("Users Admin Level: " + timeraccess);
            if ( timeraccess.equals("1")) {
                this.dispose();
                new menu().setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("Access Granted");
            }else
                System.out.println("Access Restricted.");
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        txt_staffID.setText(e.toString());
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

This, as it stands, outputs:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Where taking out the Class.forName outputs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gearheads
```

Please help me. This link is a screenshot of my libraries.

My Libraries:

[image]

Comment: Which version of the MySQL drivers are you using?  For MySQL Connector/J 8.x, the driver classname that you are using is incorrect.

Comment: Where would I find this?

Comment: In the place where you configured the MySQL driver library in your project / IDE.  Or by looking inside your WAR file.

Comment: MySQL Driver Java 5.1.23, but I've also brought in the the MySQL 8.0.21.jar

Every tutorial I've found keeps calling

`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` or `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. I've tried both, same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its runnning correctly inside Netbeans, then the MySQL driver is correct.

You have to search for Manifest file (MANIFEST.MF) and *probably* will have to unjar the contents of the driver inside your own JAR file.

<del>I'll leave this answer by now, but will try to gather the details to bring it back here.</del>

I also use NetBeans and when I generate the JAR file, its already copying the dependant libraries and generating the correct MANIFEST.MF.

I ended up with the following structure

```
MyProject\dist\lib\JdbcDriver.jar
and
MyProject\dist\MyProject.jar
```

Inside MyProject.jar, I have the following MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.7
Created-By: 1.8.0_201-b09 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/JdbcDriver.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: myproject.MyMainClass
```

Please, verify with you are copying the lib folder altogether with your JAR file.

---

Just to leave here the final solution (@Nick Media final comment): you have to check "Copy Dependent Libraries" in Build>Packaging Project Properties.

Comment: The Driver is prepacked with NetBeans 8.2 with the JDK, but I'm not sure how to do the MANIFEST or unjar the contents.

Comment: Please, tell me how is the tab Libraries>Run. Mine is with the following entries: Classpath for Compiling Sources AND Compiled Sources

Comment: Note that if you create an executable JAR like that, then the JVM needs to always be able to find the JdbcDriver.jar relative to the location of the MyProject.jar

Comment: Yes! That's why I'm asking him to verify it he is copying the lib folder altogether with the main JAR file... ;-)

Comment: @Nick Media, please, tell also how is the Build>Packaging in Project Properties...
Mine has a check in "Copy Dependent Libraries"

Comment: Literally inputting the Copy Dependent Libraries worked... Thank you so much guys :D

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear exactly what you are doing wrong, but you are clearly doing something incorrectly:

1. It is often better to use `DriverManager.getConnection` rather than `Class.forName` and a specific driver class name.  This is the approach recommended by the Oracle Java Tutorial; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html
2. If you are loading the driver via its classname, use `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` with MySQL Connector/J 5.x and `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` with MySQL Connector/J 8.x.
3. If this is a webapp, make sure that the relevant driver JAR file is actually in your WAR file, and/or that it is being deployed correctly.
4. If this is a command line app, make sure that you include the driver JAR on the **runtime** classpath.  (Especially if you are trying to run it outside of your IDE.)  Alternatively, consider creating a shaded JAR that included all of the apps dependencies.  (It is a bit hard to advise since you haven't told us if you are using a build tool like Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc.)
5. The driver doesn't actually need to be a *compile time* dependency, though there is little harm in doing that.  (The harm is that you might accidentally add imports to the MySQL implementation classes to your app ... and run into problems.)

Comment: It's a JFrame application. It works perfectly when not build, but as soon as I "Clean and Build", and run the packed .jar, it gives these errors.

I've tried to run with both the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` and `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`, and they both run fine in NetBeans itself, but again, not when the .JAR is built, so the Drivers are working, it's just not being found once it's made into the Distributable .JAR File

Comment: Well that is the problem.  I'm not an expert with NetBeans, but something about the way you are creating the executable JAR is incorrect.